# Как сделать выборку по ID из нескольких таблиц с одинаковыми полями?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ms-access

**Имеется**
Таблица (или запрос..) выборки:
    -  Таблица 00_Tb_1

Таблицы **"источники данных"**:
  - Таблица 00_Tb_2
  - Таблица 00_Tb_3
  - Таблица 00_Tb_4

Таблицы **"источника данных"**  имеют одинаковые поля.
В таблицах **"источниках данных"** поле **"Tb_ZP_id" (ключ)** уникально внутри таблицы и вне таблицы, т.е. не совпадает во всех таблицах.

**Вопрос**
Как сделать, чтобы в  **"Таблица 00_Tb_1"** выполнялся сценарий:
    - добавляем запись;
    - вводим в поле **"Tb_ZP_id"** значение **id**;
   в результате в поля (XAr_1, XAr_2, XAr_3) таблицы **"Таблица 00_Tb_1"** подтягивались значения  из таблиц **"источников данных"**, соответствующие  введённому **"Tb_ZP_id"**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите вставить только 2 значения - Tb_1_id, Tb_ZP_id, а все данные заполнились сами автоматом, то потребуется создать триггер. Сделать это можно следующей командой:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mytrigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `00_Tb_1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.XAr_1 = (SELECT XAr_1 FROM 00_Tb_2 WHERE Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id
UNION SELECT XAr_1 FROM 00_Tb_3 WHERE 00_Tb_3.Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id
UNION SELECT XAr_1 FROM 00_Tb_4 WHERE 00_Tb_4.Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id),
NEW.XAr_2 = (SELECT XAr_2 FROM 00_Tb_2 WHERE Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id
UNION SELECT XAr_2 FROM 00_Tb_3 WHERE 00_Tb_3.Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id
UNION SELECT XAr_2 FROM 00_Tb_4 WHERE 00_Tb_4.Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id),
NEW.XAr_3 = (SELECT XAr_3 FROM 00_Tb_2 WHERE Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id
UNION SELECT XAr_3 FROM 00_Tb_3 WHERE 00_Tb_3.Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id
UNION SELECT XAr_3 FROM 00_Tb_4 WHERE 00_Tb_4.Tb_ZP_id = NEW.Tb_ZP_id)
```

После создания триггера выполняем простой запрос вида:

```
INSERT INTO `00_Tb_1` (Tb_1_id, Tb_ZP_id) VALUES (5, 300)
```

XAr_1, XAr_2, XAr_3 подтянутся автоматом, если они есть в какой-либо из таблиц

Триггер на изменение значений в таблице 00_Tb_2 (остальные делаем по аналогии):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `upd_trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `00_Tb_2` 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE `00_Tb_1` SET `XAr_1` = NEW.XAr_1, `XAr_2` = NEW.XAr_2, `XAr_3`= NEW.XAr_3 WHERE 00_Tb_1.Tb_ZP_id=NEW.Tb_ZP_id;
```

При изменении любого из полей XAr - данные в таблице 00_Tb_1 обновляются автоматически.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы предлагаете постоянно вводить данные в запрос.. В частности в строку "SET id = 300;" Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы : "чтобы в "Таблица 00_Tb_1" выполнялся сценарий:
- добавляем запись;
- вводим в поле "Tb_ZP_id" значение id;
в результате в поля (XAr_1, XAr_2, XAr_3) таблицы "Таблица 00_Tb_1" подтягивались значения из таблиц "источников данных", соответствующие введённому "Tb_ZP_id"?"

Comment: @koverflow Дописал ответ, просто создайте триггер и выполняйте вставку так, как написано выше

Comment: в принципе суть понял.. А можно сделать как-то чтобы, если  в поле `XAr_1`вносятся изменения в любой из таблиц где оно используется и эти изменения отображались во всех таблицах где это поле используется? Или нужно структуру БД менять? Или триггеры дополнительные делать?

Comment: @koverflow не совсем понял, имеется в виду, если в таблицах 00_Tb_2,3,4 вносятся изменения в полях XAr_1,2,3, то автоматически внести эти изменения и в таблицу 00_Tb_1?

Comment: Да.. если в таблицах 00_Tb_2,3,4 вносятся изменения в полях XAr_1,2,3, то автоматически внести эти изменения отображаются и в таблице 00_Tb_1. И если в любой таблице где находятся поля XAr_1,2,3 внести изменения в поля XAr_1,2,3, то они отображаются в остальных таблицах где находятся поля XAr_1,2,3.. P.S. Я пока только осваиваю, поэтому делайте скидку, на то, если не грамотно формулирую решение. Допускаю, что в данном случае может мне стоит пересмотреть структуру базы

Comment: @koverflow поправил ответ, дописал пример триггера на изменение. Можете сделать тоже самое для всех таблиц - должно работать.
По поводу структуры - не понимаю зачем вам нужно именно копировать данные из 3 других таблиц в первую и поддерживать их актуальность. Нужно описание задачи, тогда можно будет что-то советовать :)
P.S. Мне кажется этот вопрос уже решен. Создавайте другой или пишите в личку